# How to change my name on Google products?

Tags: google-account-profile

I haven't changed it three times in 90 days so I know that's not it. I go to change my name and it just shows an error. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the error message you receive (which you didn't mention). If it's 503 (as usual in this case) then all you can do is wait and try again later. Also, it depends where you attempting to change the name. This is the proper way:

- go to **https://aboutme.google.com/u/0/#name**
- click on that pen icon and change your name:

[image]

[image]